# How would I access this data inside of a JSON array with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to access a certain array inside of a JSON array, I can not seem to figure out how to access this data, any help would be appreciated!

Here is the JSON array: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a37852a7436d31289390

It has no unique identifier, thats why I'm having trouble accessing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want to access country name from this json data. and you have stored that json data in **$geocode** variable, Then you can do following. This will give you exact value of key whose key name is country, no matter on which index it is.

$output= json_decode($geocode);

```
foreach($output->results[0]->address_components as $key=>$val)
{
            if($val->types[0]=='country' || $val->types[1]=='country')
            {
                $country=$output->results[0]->address_components[$key]->long_name;
            }
}
```

If you are sure about index value you can acess it as below

$country =$output->results[0]->address_components[5]->long_name;

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 2):

You should simple use `json_decode` function and then you will have PHP array that you can access without a problem

Answer (score 0):

USe `json_decode()`. It will give you an array value.

Answer (score 0):

First check your json string in **http://jsonlint.com** it's invalid json.

Check the following example:

```
<?php

   $jsonString = '{
    "results": [
        {
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "Snip",
                    "short_name": "Snip",
                    "types": [
                        "street_number"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Snip",
                    "short_name": "Snip",
                    "types": [
                        "route"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Desert Ridge",
                    "short_name": "Desert Ridge",
                    "types": [
                        "neighborhood",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Snip",
                    "short_name": "Snip",
                    "types": [
                        "locality",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Snip",
                    "short_name": "Snip",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_3",
                        "political"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}';

// Converting Json String to php jsonArray
$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString);

// Initially its started with an object so you can't access like an array
//echo '<pre>';
//print_r($jsonArray);

// If you want to use results array check the following code
$results = $jsonArray->results;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);

/*
 * If you want to access address_components key in first set of
 * results then you need to use $resluts[0]->address_components[0]
 * because every array have multiple objects, check the jsonArray
 * once before accessing it wheather it is an array or object.
 */
print_r($results[0]->address_components[0]);
?>
```